# How to deal with env files in monorepo?

Tags: javascript, lerna

How to deal with `env` files in monorepo with lerna? 
I was wondering if I should have one `env` file in the root of the repository for every app? or should each app have it's own `env` file?

I can't find any references to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the env file in the root the packages will not recognize it,
let's assume that you have 3 project 
 - web
 - mobile
 - services ( used in web and mobile)
you have to put the `.env` file in web and mobile